# Regexp. isolate string of three words with last one in quotes

Tags: c#, regex

Look, please, how do I make the regular expression in C #, that was a sequence of three words, and the last word is wrapped in double quotes. Example.from  string should be isolate substring :

> **set vrouter "Trust-Gi"**

.  I have such a code, but regular exp is made wrong ..

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadLines(opendialog.FileName);
            string pattern = @"set vrouter ".*"";
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    if (match.Success)
                        textBox1.AppendText(match.Value + '\n');
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+""([\w-]+)""");
```

Given the input `set vrouter "Trust-Gi"`, the matching groups will contain the following:

```
// m.Groups[1].Value == set
// m.Groups[2].Value == vrouter
// m.Groups[3].Value == Trust-Gi
```

And here's the same code expanded out with explanatory comments:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"
    (\w+)           # one or more word characters; captured into group 1
    \s+             # one or more spaces
    (\w+)           # one or more word characters; captured into group 2
    \s+             # one or more spaces
    ""([\w-]+)""    # one or more word characters or dash, surrounded by double-quotes; captured into group 3
", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

**EDIT:**

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""");
```

Then the router name will be in `m.Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: such regexp outputs all sequences of type ( somthing_word somthing_word "something_word")/

but i need set vrouter "someting-word" exactly. Thank you!

Comment: Added more specific regex.